# помогите сравнить результаты возвращяемые от метода

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);

        //how many times java will go throw the for-loop
        фSystem.out.println(" enter loopTimes");
        int repeatQuestions = userInput.nextInt();

        //variables
        int count;
        int result = 0;

        //if repeatQuestions = 2;loop will run 2 times
        for(count = 0; count < repeatQuestions; count++)
        {
            //first run Part: display 0,second time Part: will display 1
            System.out.println("Part: " + count);
            //prompt first number
            System.out.println("Enter first number");
            int numberOne = userInput.nextInt();
            //prompt second number
            System.out.println("Enter second number");
            int numberTwo = userInput.nextInt();
            //passing parameters to method and store result in variable
            result = adding2Numbers(numberOne, numberTwo);

            //*** enter your code here ***

        }

        //display last number that was stored in variable result
        System.out.println(result);

        /*
         * Run: 
         * repeatQuestions = 2;
         * 
         * At Part: 0
         * numberOne = 2;
         * numberTwo = 3;
         * result = 5;
         * 
         * At Part: 1
         * numberOne = 5;
         * numberTwo = 6;
         * result = 11;
         * 
         *??? How to compare which result is bigger in Part:0 or Part:1 ???
         */

        userInput.close();

    }

    /**
     * @param method adding two number together
     * @return sum of two number that method is received
     */
    public static int adding2Numbers(int numberOne, int numberTwo) {

        int result = numberOne + numberTwo;

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: Может приведете свое решение задачи?

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = 0;
```

Меняем на:

```
int result[] = new int[2];
```

А это:

```
result = adding2Numbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
```

Поменять на это:

```
result[count] = adding2Numbers(numberOne, numberTwo);
```

А потом спокойно сравниваем `result[0]` и `result[1]`

**UPD:** Ну если код можно вставить ТОЛЬКО в цикле и нельзя трогать исходный код то:

Переменную `int oldResult = 0;` за пределами цикла все таки надо добавить. После чего делаем так:

```
if(oldResult>result){
   result=oldResult;
}else{
   oldResult=result;
}
```

**PS** А за постановку вопроса щелбан надо поставить.

Comment: Из условия задачи видно что можно только вставить код, но не надругаться над тем что уже есть. Сам вопрос содержится в приведенном исходнике. Решение не привожу потому как это противоречит правилам.

Comment: @ Sergey Mitrofanov Я не говорю что задания нет, я говорю что вопрос оформлен из рук вон плохо.